# What is the best pattern for event notification with different arguments?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm looking for an alternative pattern to the following (method 1):

```
public interface IEventListener {
    void onFoo(String string, Integer integer, ObjectB objectB);
    void onBar(Double d, ObjectA objectA);
}
```

I'm thinking something like this (method 2):

```
public interface IEventListener {
    void onEvent(Event event);
}

public enum EVENT_TYPE {
    FOO, BAR
}

public abstract class Event {
    EVENT_TYPE type;
    abstract EVENT_TYPE getType();
}

public class FooEvent extends Event {
    private String string;
    private Integer integer;
    private ObjectB objectB;

    @Override
    EVENT_TYPE getType() {
        return EVENT_TYPE.FOO;
    }
}

public class BarEvent extends Event {
    private Double d;
    private ObjectA objectA;

    @Override
    EVENT_TYPE getType() {
        return EVENT_TYPE.BAR;
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how it is easy to use.
To handle the event I need to check the event type and cast the event to the correct one, etc.

Maybe there is no alternative to method 1?

Comment: This depends a _lot_ on what environment you're running in. Note that it very much appears you need some more research on Java idioms and conventions, as `I` for interfaces generally isn't used, your enum should be named `EventType`, _and_ the enum probably isn't necessary (`Class<E extends Event>` is more typical).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks for your comment I know the conversion..its some fast coding for the example..

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from common ancestors until you have a clear reason to deal with abstract events (like some logging, timing, queueing, serialization, etc...).

It's a lot simpler to code listeners as lambdas too. You would do well to think about classes of listeners actually, like Consumer<Foo> and Consumer<Bar>.

The event provider would implement something like
addFooListener(Consumer<Foo> listener) {...}

The handler might have
public void handleFoo(Foo foo) {...}

and the setup code would init
provider.addFooListener(somehandler::handleFoo);

Comment: Im not sure that I got your idea. See this please and complete the rest if it is possible: https://codeshare.io/5Ny8xr

Comment: I didn't understand the Generic class (Consumer) necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern I use sometimes is to have the listener methods be empty default methods and then override each of them in a functional interface subtype that can be created with a lambda, like this:

```
public interface IEventListener {
    default void onFoo(String string, Integer integer, ObjectB objectB){}
    default void onBar(Double d, ObjectA objectA){}
    interface OnFoo extends IEventListener {
        @Override void onFoo(String string, Integer integer, ObjectB objectB);
    }
    interface OnBar extends IEventListener {
        @Override void onBar(Double d, ObjectA objectA);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it either with an anonymous class that implements multiple methods you want to recieve or a lambda that just listens for one:

```
object.addListener((OnBar)(d, a) -> System.out.println(d));
```

You could still use this with event objects like `FooEvent` from the question which could be a good idea if you may change the arguments in the future, since you might only need to add a field to `FooEvent` instead of rewriting all of your listener implementations.

```
default void onFoo(FooEvent event){}
```

I think this is better for when you have many listeners that each need to listen for a subset of the events, but I've also used your method 2 from the question before when I needed to process all of the events only in one place.